# HOC which passes all props

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, higher-order-components

I am thinking about writing some React's util (probably HOC) which allows me to test such kind of code:

```
    const wrapper = enzyme
      .mount(
        withTestTheme(
          <JsonInput
            onChange={onChange}
            onValueChange={mockOnValueChange}
            value={exampleJsonStringValidated}
          />),
      );
```

`withTestTheme` is a wrapper which delivers theme's properties but it make me issue during testing because it causes issues to access to the root component which I want to test. Any ideas on some useful util to easier test above code?

Below `withTestTheme` which delivers theme - light and dark:

```
export const withTestTheme = (Component: React.ReactChild) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={TestTheme}>
  {Component}
</ThemeProvider>
);
```

Comment: Can you let me know what the withTestTheme does? library or custom? Please share code if its custom.

Comment: "it causes issues to access to the root component which I want to test" - what do you mean here? does it prevent your from accessing `.find(YourComponentConstructor)`? or do you mean accessing `wrapper.instance()` or `wrapper.setState()`(that you better avoid anyway)?

Comment: Sure, I explain. My issue is that console.log(wrapper.find(JsonInput)) is empty because withTestTheme is a wrapper. I want to check following test:         expect(wrapper.find(JsonInput).hasClass(':valid')).toEqual(true); and due to withTestTheme I cannot because wrapper has access to only root. I want to make in some way that JsonInput will be the root on wrapper using also withTestTheme features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code which solved my issue:

```
export const withTestThemeWrapper = (props: { children: React.ReactElement }) => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={TestTheme}>
    {props.children}
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```